# Не срабатывают flex в классах Bootstrap (React)

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
            <Container>
                <h2 className="text-center m-4">Our Team</h2>
                <CardDeck>
                    <Card className="d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">
                        <Card.Img 
                        variant="top" 
                        src="https://telegra.ph/file/1dde1b056f0b74fe8d6e3.jpg"
                        />
                        <Card.Body>
                            <Card.Title className="text-center">Developers</Card.Title>
                            <Card.Text>Lorem</Card.Text>
                            <Button variables="primary">Заказать</Button>
                        </Card.Body>
                    </Card>
                </CardDeck>
            </Container>
```

Почему не срабатывают классы указанные в теге Card?

Comment: CSS подключить забыл поэтому и не срабатывают. `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';`

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов всё подключено (включено), проблему частично решил переписав классы Card.Body